# $X$ and $Y$ are i.i.d. $\mathcal N(0,1)$, why $X/Y$ and $X/|Y|$ have the same distribution?

Tags: probability, self-study, distributions, normal-distribution

$X$ and $Y$ are i.i.d. $\mathcal N(0,1)$, why $X/Y$ and $X/|Y|$ have the same distribution?

Comment: In short, because the distribution of $X$ is symmetric about zero.

Comment: Consider the relationships between the signs of $X$, $Y$ and the two ratios.

Comment: It is because Y and |Y| have the same distribution.

Comment: @MichaelChernick $\Pr(Y < 0) = \frac12$, $\Pr(\lvert Y \rvert < 0) = 0$....

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/330607/119261

Answer (score 1):

Since this is self-study I'm just going to outline one way to do this. The basic approach is to prove the two RVs have the same distribution by showing their CDFs are equal.

Begin with
$$
P(X/Y \leq z) = P(X/Y \leq z, Y \leq 0) + P(X/Y \leq z, Y > 0)
$$

$$
= P(X \geq zY, Y \leq 0) + P(X \leq zY, Y > 0)
$$

$$
= P(X \geq -z|Y|, Y \leq 0) + P(X \leq z|Y|, Y > 0).
$$

Can you turn this into $P(X / |Y| \leq z)$?

Answer (score 1):

Proof outline:

1. Prove the distribution of magnitudes and signs of the two random variables are the same.
2. For each random variable, the magnitude and sign are independent.

Answer (score 1):

I show the two random variables have the same distribution by showing that they have the same CDF. Let $T_1=X/Y$ and $T_2=X/|Y|$.

\begin{align}
F_{T_1}&=P(X/Y<t)=P(X<Yt, Y>0).P(Y>0) +P(X>Yt , Y<0).P(Y<0)\ 
\\
F_{T_2}&=P(X<|Y|t)=P(X<Yt, Y>0).P(Y>0) +P(X<-Yt , Y<0).P(Y<0)
\end{align}

Since $X$ is symmetric about zero then
$P(X>Yt, Y<0)=P(X<-Yt, Y<0)$
Hence, $T_1$ and $T_2$ have the same distribution.

Comment: Isn't this identical to the answer already posted by jld?