# Distribution of the ratio of two i.i.d standard normals

Tags: probability, distributions, normal-distribution, cauchy-distribution

I am reading an article in which the author states that given two i.i.d random variables $X,Y\sim\mathcal{N}(0,1)$, we have $\mathbb{P}(\frac{X}{Y}\le t)=\mathbb{P}(\frac{X}{|Y|}\le t)$ since the random varaibles $\frac{X}{Y}$ and $\frac{X}{|Y|}$ are identically distributed by the symmetry of the standard normal distribution.

But I don't really understand why the random variables $\frac{X}{Y}$ and $\frac{X}{|Y|}$ are identically distributed. Can you provide a reason for why these two random variables are identically distributed?

Comment: Even without the symmetry argument, one can derive both distributions to show that they have the standard Cauchy distribution. This has already been done in multiple posts here.

Comment: @StubbornAtom the difference between answers from mathematicians and statisticians (or physicists/engineers to which I associate more closely) is certainly amusing and worthwhile for meta-discussion.

Comment: Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068). Each community should have an honest shot at answering without anybody's time being wasted.

Comment: Previously asked: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/243849/x-and-y-are-i-i-d-mathcal-n0-1-why-x-y-and-x-y-have-the-same-di

Comment: Also see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1477420/distribution-of-y-fracx-1x-2?rq=1.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are different way to see this.

**1**

The top side (y positive) is a (point symmetric) mirror image of the bottom side (y negative). So you can express $P(\frac{x}{y}|y<0)$ by $P(\frac{x}{y}|y>0)$ and similarly $P(\frac{x}{|y|}|y<0)$ by $P(\frac{x}{|y|}|y>0)$

**2**

- $\frac{x}{y}=b$ occurs when $\frac{x}{y}=b$ for $y>0$ and $\frac{x}{y}=b$ for $y<0$
- $\frac{x}{|y|}=b$ occurs when $\frac{x}{y}=b$ for $y>0$ and $\frac{x}{y}=-b$ for $y<0$

thus effectively you flip the bottom half from $\frac{x}{y}=b$ to $\frac{x}{y}=-b$ but this half is symmetric in $P(\frac{x}{y}|y<0) = P(-\frac{x}{y}|y<0)$

**3**

a conversion to cyclic coordinates may also work. $P(\frac{x}{y}=a) \propto   2 P(\theta=tan^{-1}(a))$ and also $P(\frac{x}{|y|}=a) \propto 2 P(\theta=tan^{-1}(a))$

> *image: 1000 points x,y distributed i.i.d. N(0,1)*
>
> [image: 1000 points x,y distributed i.i.d. N(0,1)]

Answer (score 2):

Setting $B=\frac{X}{|X|}$ and $C=\frac{Y}{|Y|}$ we have $B,C,|X|,|Y|$ independent.

Observe that $\frac{X}{Y}=\frac{B}{C}\frac{|X|}{|Y|}$ and $\frac{X}{|Y|}=B\frac{|X|}{|Y|}$.

It is not difficult to prove that  $\frac{B}{C}$ and $B$ have the same distribution.

Answer (score 2):

If you look at a Cartesian plane, then given any t, the points where $\frac{x}{y}$ = t will be a line with slope $\frac{1}{t}$. That is, the equation of the line will be x=ty. The points where $\frac{x}{|y|}$ = t will be that line with the bottom half reflected horizontally.  That is, for negative y, the equation will become x= -ty. So by including that absolute value, we are, for negative y values, going from looking for P(x=2y<sub>0</sub>, y=y<sub>0</sub>) to looking for P(x= -2y<sub>0</sub>, y=y<sub>0</sub>). But because the normal distribution is symmetric, the probabilities are the same.